# updating a nested dictionary getting ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am connecting to my mongodb using pymongo and trying to append to a nested dictionary using the code:

```
myquery = User.objects.filter(username=current_user)
my_dict = myquery[0]['spare_2']
my_dict[quiz_id] = {'question1': 9, 'question2': 9, 'question3': 9, 'question4': 9, 'question5': 9, 'question6': 9, 'question7': 9, 'question8': 9, 'question9': 9, 'question10': 9}
User.objects(username=current_user).update(spare_2=my_dict)
```

I am getting the error:

[image]

How can I solve this? I'm a home coding enthusiast so not very knowledgeable on why this is happening, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I was updating the dictionary and it solved the problem:

```
myquery = User.objects.filter(username=current_user)
my_dict = myquery[0]['spare_2']
append_dict = {quiz_id: 9, 'question2': 9, 'question3': 9, 'question4': 9, 'question5': 9, 'question6': 9, 'question7': 9, 'question8': 9, 'question9': 9, 'question10': 9}
new_dict = my_dict | append_dict
User.objects(username=current_user).update(spare_2=new_dict)
```